# Bootstrap 4 Card Group's

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've been playing with the new card group compontent in Bootstrap 4 but have the following issue:

When using a card group with 2 rows the borders will be doubled meaning the top row (4) and bottom (also 4) will have an extra line between them.

```
        <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row">

      <div class="card-group">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-block">
            <h5 class="card-title">1</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-block">
            <h5 class="card-title">2</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-block">
            <h5 class="card-title">3</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-block">
            <h5 class="card-title">4</h5>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="card-group">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-block">
            <h5 class="card-title">1</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-block">
            <h5 class="card-title">2</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-block">
            <h5 class="card-title">3</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-block">
            <h5 class="card-title">4</h5>
          </div>
        </div>


    </div>
  </div>
```

Does anyone know how to apply these 2 rows properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You **don't need** the extra markup to using `.card-group`.

- Columns must be placed **inside** rows, not vice versa.
- Setting only one column with `.col-md-12` is redundant, because it mean 100% of width.
- You only should use `.container` or `.container-fluid` and place your cards there directly, using card-groups as a row, that works because `.card-group` have `display: table;` and each card within have `display: table-cell` so it will work as column.

> Here is an **example** without the extra markup: **http://www.bootply.com/3Zb4ybq1iH**

That's how Bootstrap grid works.

- The `.container` or `.container-fluid` have a horizontal **padding** of `0.9375rem` to separate your content of the edges of the browser.
- When you need to divide a row into columns, you use the class `.row` which have a *(negative)* horizontal **margin** of `-0.9375rem` that **resets** the padding of the container.
- But each column have a horizontal **padding** of `0.9375rem` and you have again that separation of the edge of the browser, but now on each column.

A few tips about [**grid system**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) that you can find in the documentation of Bootstrap 3, that also works for Bootstrap 4.

> - Rows must be placed within a `.container` (fixed-width) or `.container-fluid` (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.
> - Use rows to create horizontal groups of columns.
> - Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows.
> - Grid columns are created by specifying the number of twelve available columns you wish to span. For example, three equal columns would use three `.col-xs-4`

Comment: Thanks for clearing up things, but this doesn't help me currently with the extra line between the two rows..

Comment: I updated the post and added [**this expample**](http://www.bootply.com/3Zb4ybq1iH) to explain what I'm talking about unnecessary and wrong markup.